# Why my intel xdk app don't work on android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, intel-xdk

I'm learning jQuery and I built my project using xdk, but square is not moving(when button is clicked). I checked it on android 4.4. and nothing(it's working on my pc). Can you help me?
This is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/T9y7t/

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="intelxdk.js"> </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="all">
            <input id="up" type="button" value="UP">
            <br>
            <input id="lewy" type="button" value="LEWO">
            <input id="prawy" type="button" value="PRAWO">
            <br>
            <input id="down" type="button" value="DOWN">
            <div id="game">
                <div id="cube">
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

style.css:

```
html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
body, div, h1, h2, h3, ul, li, span, img, input {
margin:0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}
    body{
        background-color: black;
    }
#container {


}

#all{
font-size: 20px;
color:white;
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: auto;
height: auto;
background-color: :white;

}
input {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#game{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
top:+10px;
display: block;
background-color: yellow;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;



}  

#cube{
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var left = $("#lewy");
    var right = $("#prawy");
    var cube = $("#cube");
    var up = $("#up");
    var down = $("#down");
    var krok = "10px";
    left.click(function () {
        cube.animate({
            left: "-=" + krok
        }, "fast");
        intel.xdk.notification.vibrate();
    });
    right.click(function () {
        cube.animate({
            left: "+=" + krok
        }, "fast");
        intel.xdk.notification.vibrate();
    });
    down.click(function () {
        cube.animate({
            top: "+=" + krok
        }, "fast");
        intel.xdk.notification.vibrate();
    });
    up.click(function () {
        cube.animate({
            top: "-=" + krok
        }, "fast");
        intel.xdk.notification.vibrate();
    });

});
```

Edit: i tried other build options (crosswalk/cordova) but still nothing

Comment: Just a silly question but do you have an active internet connection on your Droid device ? Since you are referring to `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">`

Comment: yes i have wi-fi connection

Answer (score 0):

yes, It can be happen, some times,because mobile is the different platform and web is different

if your app works in emulator but not in device, then The api is blocked due to Cross domain access, which is the same reason why your code will not work in any browser. But there is a way to make it work in Intel XDK apps, just add  after your intelxdk.js script inclusion. It will then work on device.

More info about AJAX and XDK here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/how-to-access-JSON-data-in-HTML5-apps

Comment: I don't understand why? It works in emulator, it works in my chrome so why it is not working on my device?

Comment: I checked xdk demo apps and none of them have this

Comment: I wrote already that This is due to cross domain access, to resolve this you need to include this line in your code <script src="xhr.js"></script>

Comment: I need to show your code,mail me your full code on velocitysoftware21@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try including `<script src="xhr.js"></script>` after the `<script src="indelxdk.js"></script>` inclusion.